# Nginx: redirected you too many times

Tags: ssl, nginx

I'm getting **'mysite.com' redirected you too many times**. Here is my nginx config.

```
server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name mysite.com;
    server_tokens off;


    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.php index.html;


  location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
  }

 location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I'm using certbot and this is running on a ubuntu docker container, serving static html files.

The lock icon by the left side of the url shows its **locked** and the connection is secure.

Comment: Assuming you are seeing that msg after visiting `http://...` - browsers can cache  redirect info, even after you've changed the nginx config. Try clearing your browser cache, quitting and restarting your browser.  If that doesn't help, edit your question and describe what URL you are visiting, and what devtools shows is the response, which redirects are happening, etc.

Comment: If i visit http://..., it will redirect me to https://... according to the configuration and it does.
But if I visit https://... it gives me the message, **redirected you too many times.**. I've tried after clearing my cached data. Tried with different browsers. The response is the same. I tried to request with postman but postman gave me **Could not get any response** .

Comment: If that is your Nginx configuration, where is the code to handle `.php` requests?

Comment: I do have a configuration for php-fpm ( please check the description, updated )

and besides, I only have an index.html, so there is no .php and the **index** is set up to look for index.php , followed by index.html.

but the result is the same.

Comment: 1) Keep it simple. If the current problem has nothing to do with PHP, remove everything PHP related.  Reducing everything to a  [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) often helps find the root problem. 2) You still didn't report what the redirects are.  You say if you visit https://... you see the redirect error - there are no redirects configured for https so that does not seem correct.  Check your devtools, where is https redirecting?